# Creating a flag in C through PPM

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, printf, ppm

I am trying to design the Denmark flag in C through PPM but I can't seem to get my function to work as well as I want to find a more efficient way to loop all the places together, instead of doing all if/else if statements.

```
 for(i=0; i < height; i++){
  for(x=0; x < width; x++){
    if(x <= width *.3 && i <= height * .3)
   {
     printf("%i", Pixel(255,51,51));
   }
    else if(x<= width * .1 && i <= height *.1)
   {
     printf("%i",Pixel(0,0,0));
   }
    else if(x <= width * .405 && i <= height *.3)
   {
     printf("%i", Pixel(255,51,51));
   }
    else if(x <= width * .4 && i <= height)
   {
     printf("%i", Pixel(0,0,0));
   }
    else
   {
     printf("%i", Pixel(255,51,51));
   }
 }
}
```

This is my body, which I have no idea how to loop together instead of creating mass amounts of if/else statements which half the time probably wont work....

```
void Pixel(int red, int green, int blue){
  printf("%i %i %i", red, green, blue);
}
```

Also for some reason my function will compile... Can anyone help me with this issue as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on how to use logical operators `&&` and `||`.

There is no need to add separate checks for 'left red, middle white, right red', you can *assume* you are drawing in red and only check for the middle part.

Since you want to draw in White when [x > 0.3 && x <= 0.4] *or* [y > 0.3 && y <= 0.4], you can concatenate this into a single `if` check. The same goes for the black border -- it only needs a single check.

```
if (x < width * .1 || y < height * .1 || x > width * .9 || y > height * .9)
  ..black..
else
  if ((x > width *.3 && x <= width * .4) || (y > height *.3 && y <= height * .4))
    ..white..
  else
    ..red..
```

Also: Your Pixel routine *already* prints the RGB value, so there is no need to try that again when you call it. What happens now is that

```
printf("%i", Pixel(255,51,51));
```

first prints the R,G,B values and then *attempts to* print the 'result' of calling the `Pixel` function. This fails because `Pixel` does not return a value. *Your compiler should have warned you about that*, so please check your compile settings. (But note that adding a `return x` statement in that function does not help a bit, because it calculates nothing you are interested in.)

Finally, I'd strongly recommed using `y` instead of `i` to iterate a clearly-Y value. I noticed I used that 'instinctively' in my explanation.

After fixing a few smaller issues (for instance, `Pixel` outputs three digits separated by a space, but if you call it a second time, the first new digit will stick to the previous one) I got this:

[image: flag of Denmark]

in PPM format, which I could open correctly in Photoshop (and then convert to PNG because SO does not like PPM images).

Comment: Ah thanks so much!!! I have been trying to figure out the ratio in of each border and I was using wikipedia.... looks like I was off a tad when using their width to height ratio.

Comment: In my book they have always used i so that was something I have always followed, but I definitly understand where you are coming from with y placement. Thanks again! @Jongware

Comment: If this answers your question, you could consider accepting it.